# Issue migrating WSE 2.0 to 3.0

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-services, wse

I am trying to migrating WSE 2.0 to 3.0 (This is a windows service that will consume WSDL)

For that I created a Custom policy PolicyAssertion, but in '**ProcessMessage**' envelope I am not getting any Security information. I am using username password authentication.

Without  security tag my service not working. how to solve this?